# Como somar os valores de cada linha de uma matriz?

Tags: java, matriz

Como somar os valores de cada linha de uma matriz e armazenar a soma em um *array*? Exemplo:

```
3 3 3 
2 3 4
2 2 2
```

Resulta em:

```
9
9
6
```

Comment: e armazenar a soma em uma array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que você deve iniciar pensando em usar um laço `for`

Exemplo para ajudar...

```
int[][] num = new int[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < num[i].length; j++) {
        sum += num[j][i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: tenho algo assim     for (i=0; i<eq;i++){  
              masG[i]=masG[i]+puntos[i][j];
              for(j=0; j<eq;j++){
               
               if(i==j){puntos[i][j]=0;}
               else{
                soma+=puntos[i][j];
                masG[i]=soma;
               }
              }

Comment: desculpa assim na verdade  for (i=0; i<eq;i++){  
              
              for(j=0; j<eq;j++){
               
               if(i==j){puntos[i][j]=0;}
               else{
                soma+=puntos[i][j];
                masG[i]=soma;
               }
              }

Comment: Marcio, fica dificil analisar o codigo que você enviou. Acho legal você analisar melhor o codigo e tentar "debugar" para entender o que o laço está fazendo.